# How to add cookbooks from chef documentation

Tags: maven, chef-infra, cookbook, opennebula

I am a new to chef cookbooks and currently working on a task. I have already completed the tutorial on chef.io but i am struggling to understand how can i install a cookbook provided at [chef-io](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/maven).

So as of now, I have downloaded the cookbook. Its .tar file and i extracted it. I can see respective default.rb and other files but i am unable to get that how can i add this cookbook to my existing cookbooks which are creating a vm image.

Is there any guide or tutorial that i can follow ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then what you need to do is create a Chef role, and then list all of the recipes that you want to execute in your role's run_list.  As for documentation, check out Chef's documentation on roles: [Chef Roles](http://docs.chef.io/roles.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Josh's answer it sounds to me like want to add it to your chef-repo after downloading it and extracting the gzip file?

> Just add the maven directory to your cookbooks directory. Or you could just do `knife cookbook site install maven` from within your chef-repo directory.

Or maybe you want to upload it to your Chef Server?

> `knife cookbook upload maven` See: https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html#upload

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if i get your question right, you are trying to download an already existing cookbook from the community. If so, you can follow these steps :

1) Download the cookbook which is in the .tar format as you specified, extract it and place that particular cookbook within your chef-repo path from where you want to upload it.

2) Once done, do a "knife cookbook upload **cookbook-name**"

Now the main part is, if you are trying to upload this cookbook and make it part of your already existing run-list. You need to add this within the run-list.

Else if you are doing it via **role**, you will need to add this cookbook  recipe within your role's run-list.

But keep in mind, whatever cookbook's you download from the community might have dependencies on other cookbook's so choose wisely. The lesser cookbook's the better as this makes your run-list converge faster for a faster chef-client run.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Akshay